# Reopen request - Different opinion led to a co-worker not working with me anymore

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Different opinion led to a co-worker not working with me anymore](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/132785/different-opinion-led-to-a-co-worker-not-working-with-me-anymore)

This question was closed as "opinion-based", but the OP wasn't asking whether we agree with his opinion.  The question he's asking is quite clear:

> I cannot understand it because my opinion and the work is something different. Did I really do something wrong here?

The OP is seeking to understand how the thoughts he expressed caused offense.  That's something we can answer (and something that has already been well answered on the question).

This question should be reopened.

Answer (score -2):

I agree that the question should be reopened. People's interactions in the workplace are the primary source of conflict in a large number of workplace issues. This is becoming especially relevant as people discover that words and/or phrases that they've used, or are industry standards, become less acceptable for more people. The OP in this question expressed one sticking point in particular with the "gender mania" issue, and there is an excellent answer that addresses this.